# What is the time complexity for binary_search function for a list type

Tags: c++, sorting, search, time-complexity, lower-bound

will it be O( n ) or O( logn ) ?

```
  list< int > myList = { 2, 6, 12, 13, 15, 18, 20};    
    cout << binary_search(myList.begin(), myList.end(), 20) ;
```

Comment: [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) or [`std::binary_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search)? (Not that it matters, as both are the same, but please don't mention one function in the title and another in the question body.)

Comment: Necessarily linear. If the needle is right in the middle of the list, it will be removed by n/2 from `begin()` or `rbegin()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> #### Complexity
>
> The number of comparisons performed is logarithmic in the distance between first and last (At most `log2(last - first) + O(1)` comparisons). However, for non-`LegacyRandomAccessIterator`s, number of iterator increments is linear.
>
> <sup>(c) [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search)</sup>

`std::list` iterators are not random-access-iterators (they are forward-iterators), so the complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks undertsood the logic

Comment: @ChhaviBansal If this answers your question, press the green tick on the left to mark your problem as solved.